# why do I get error when I want to loop

Tags: list, python-3.x

How would I loop the following code, when I use `if` statements I keep getting an error. I am trying to get the following number printed out, 511887 and Compare each 4-bit binary number using conditional statements but I keep getting an error: `NameError: name 'bin_list' is not defined`

```
x=("bin_list")

y=("bin_list[SN_0]")
["0001"]

"0101"
"0001"
"0001"
"1000"
"1000"
"0111"

SN_bin_0 = bin_list[SN_1]
for x in range (0,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_1 = bin_list[SN_5]
   for x in range (1,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_2 = bin_list[SN_1]
   for x in range (2,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)


SN_bin_3 = bin_list[SN_1]
   for x in range (3,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_4 = bin_list[SN_8]
   for x in range (4,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_5 = bin_list[SN_8]
   for x in range (5,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_6 = bin_list[SN_7]
   for x in range (6,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  It looks like your indentation is all wacky.

Comment: SN_bin_0 = bin_list[SN_1]
NameError: name 'bin_list' is not defined but I have defined the variable

Comment: from your code, it looks like you are not defining `bin_list`.  you are defining `x` and assigning it the string `"bin_list"`.  It looks like you are doing something similar with `y`.

Comment: So how can I define it correctly

Answer (score 1):

**1. Making a List**

Instead of writing:

```
["0001"]
"0101"
"0001"
"0001"
"1000"
"1000"
"0111"
```

You can make it a list:

```
bin_list = ["0101","0001","0001","1000","1000","0111"]
```

*Explanation*:

- This is the proper way of making a list: `variable = [item1,item2,item3]`
- It should be a list because later you will use an index to refer to the items inside of it. For example `bin_List[1]` will return the string `"0001"`.

**2. Value of Variable `x`**

Instead of writing:

```
x=("bin_list")
```

You should do:

```
x=(bin_list)
```

*Explanation*:

- The quotation marks on `bin_list` makes it a *string*.  You want the value of `x` to be the list `bin_list`.
- You must make create the (see **step 1**) before assigning the variable `x` to it.

**3. Value of Variable `y`**

Instead of writing:

```
y=("bin_list[SN_0]")
```

You should do:

```
y= bin_list[SN_0]
```

*Explanation*:

- The quotation marks on `bin_list[SN_0]` makes it a *string*.  You want the value of `y` to be the item at index `[SN_0]` of the list `bin_list`.

**4. Undefined variable**

The following are *undefined*:

```
[SN_0]
[SN_1]
[SN_5]
[SN_8]
L
```

Each one of them needs a value, for example:

```
SN_0 = 0
SN_1 = 1
SN_5 = 5
SN_8 = 8
L = x
```

*Explanation*:

- Undefined variables will return an error.
- They must all be defined before being used in the for loops.
- If `L` is supposed to refer to the list, you can replace it with `x` since the list is already assigned variable `x`.

**4. Indentation**

The following code has an extra indentation:

```
SN_bin_1 = bin_list[SN_5]
   for x in range (1,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_2 = bin_list[SN_1]
   for x in range (2,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)


SN_bin_3 = bin_list[SN_1]
   for x in range (3,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_4 = bin_list[SN_8]
   for x in range (4,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)
```

It should be:

```
SN_bin_1 = bin_list[SN_5]
for x in range (1,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_2 = bin_list[SN_1]
for x in range (2,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)


SN_bin_3 = bin_list[SN_1]
for x in range (3,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)

SN_bin_4 = bin_list[SN_8]
for x in range (4,7):
    for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are few issues with your code.  The following is not valid python:

```
x=("bin_list")

y=("bin_list[SN_0]")
["0001"]

"0101"
"0001"
"0001"
"1000"
"1000"
"0111"
```

I think what you wanted was to have these values in a list, which can be done like so:

```
bin_list = ["0101", "0001", "0001", "1000", "1000", "0111"]
```

Next, you are accessing the list using an undefined variable.  You need to either use an integer or define `SN_0` beforehand.

```
y = bin_list[0]
```

or

```
SN_0 = 0
y = bin_list[SN_0]
```

Finally, your indentation is off on most of the loops. You have:

```
SN_bin_1 = bin_list[SN_5]
   for x in range (1,7):
     for index in range(len(L)):
        print (y)
```

You want:

```
SN_bin_1 = bin_list[SN_5]
for x in range (1,7):        # <-- one less indent here
  for index in range(len(L)):
     print (y)
```

I can't exactly tell what your code is meant to do, it seems you are not using many of your variables, and your goal to print the value of `y` a certain amount of times.  Once you've fixed these errors, open a new question if the code is still not doing what you intended.